# Changing arrows to dashed line in smartdiagram

Tags: formatting, smartdiagram

I am trying to customize a circular diagram using smartdiagram. I have two issues:

1. I have added three additional arrows but would like these to be dashed or dotted.
2. I have added code to show text above the arrow connecting module 7 and module 6, but it is not showing up.
   Here is the current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramconnect}{m m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \foreach \start/\end in {#2}
  \draw[additional item arrow type,#1]
    (\start) to (\end);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
    \centering
\smartdiagramset{uniform color list=teal!60 for 7 items,
                    module x sep=3.75,
                    back arrow distance=0.75,
                    sequence item border color=black,
                    uniform arrow color=true,
                    arrow color=gray!50!black,
                    circular distance=5cm,
                    font=\large,
                    text width=2.5cm,
                    module minimum width=2.5cm,
                    module minimum height=1.5cm,
                    arrow line width=2.5pt,
                    arrow tip=to,
                additions={
                    additional arrow style=,
                    additional arrow color=black,               additional arrow line width=2pt,
                }
                    } 
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
    1-Define the construct,2-Identify and describe facets,3-Determine facet levels,4-Determine scenario structure,5-Develop mapping sentences and build scenarios,6-Select response options and survey instructions,7-Test (and retest)
    }
    {}
    \smartdiagramconnect{->, shorten <=8pt, shorten >=8pt, bend left=30, "no"{midway,above right,text=black}}{module7/module6}
      \smartdiagramconnect{->, shorten <=8pt, shorten >=8pt, bend left=30,}{module6/module5, module5/module4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please see the edit below if it meets the requirement

Comment: --code edited and once again uploaded afresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding dashed in the arrow style gives your first requirement

```
                additions={
                additional arrow style=dashed,
                additional arrow color=black,   
                additional arrow line width=2pt,
                          }
```

[image]

**EDIT -- for the labels**

I found it easier to apply `TiKz` which is a superset of `smartdiagram` -- deleting about 15 lines of `smartdiagramconnect` and `additions` and adding the `decorations` library the dashed arrows and labels are easily positioned

[image]

Using

```
        -stealth,
        line width=1mm,
        red!40,
        dashed,
```

the arrows are defined

With the help of decoration

```
                    postaction={decorate,
                    decoration={text along path,
                                text align=center,
                                text={Diatessaron},
                                raise=5pt}}
```

the labels are positioned and raised 5pt

With the help of

```
(module6.north east) to[out = 45, in = 85, looseness = 1.2] (module5.north 
west);
```

the anchors are provided to the corner of the module and the arrow angle of departure and arrival are added

With the help of xshift anchor position can be shifted to the left or right

```
([xshift=.5cm]module5.north) to[out = 90, in = 180, looseness = 1.2] 
(module4.west);
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} 
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,quotes,calc,decorations.text,positioning} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \smartdiagramset{uniform color list=teal!60 for 7 items,
            module x sep=3.75,
            back arrow distance=0.75,
            sequence item border color=black,
            uniform arrow color=true,
            arrow color=gray!50!black,
            circular distance=5cm,
            font=\large,
            text width=2.5cm,
            module minimum width=2.5cm,
            module minimum height=1.5cm,
            arrow line width=2.5pt,
            arrow tip=to,
        } 
        \smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
            1-Define the construct,2-Identify and describe facets,3-Determine facet levels,4-Determine scenario structure,5-Develop mapping sentences and build scenarios,6-Select response options and survey instructions,7-Test (and retest)
        }
        {}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw[-stealth,
                line width=1mm,
                red!40,
                dashed,
                postaction={decorate,
                            decoration={text along path,
                                        text align=center,
                                        text={Diatessaron},
                                        raise=5pt}}] 
        (module7.south east) to[out = -45, in = 85, looseness = 1.2] (module6.north);
        
        \draw[-stealth,
                line width=1mm,
                red!40,
                dashed,
                postaction={decorate,
                            decoration={text along path,
                                        text align=center,
                                        text={Diatessaron},
                                        raise=5pt}}] 
        (module6.north east) to[out = 45, in = 85, looseness = 1.2] (module5.north west);
        
        \draw[-stealth,
                line width=1mm,
                red!40,
                dashed,
                postaction={decorate,
                            decoration={text along path,
                                        text align=center,
                                        text={Diatessaron},
                                        raise=5pt}}] 
        ([xshift=.5cm]module5.north) to[out = 90, in = 180, looseness = 1.2] (module4.west);
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: shucks! forgot to add the complete MWE -- will do it as soon as I open up my system

Comment: I have two additional qs: 1) is there any way to make the module sizes the same? 2)is there a way to make the distance between modules the same? Perhaps by doing 1) this will happen?

Comment: @mariabc -- please accept the answer by a tick on the left hand side -- your additional queries should be put as a new question to give other members an opportunity also -- the solutions are available as I said tikz is far more flexible than smartdiagram